# How to test two returned functions with different argument value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-webpack

I have a function that returns comparisonFunction

```
  getComparisonFunction(propertyOfComparison) {
    const func = function(a, b){
      if ( a[propertyOfComparison] < b[propertyOfComparison] ) {
        return -1;
      }
      if ( a[propertyOfComparison] > b[propertyOfComparison] ) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    };

    return func;
  }
```

This method will be used inside javascript "sort" method.
for example:

```
arrayOfObjects.sort(getComparisonFunction('name'));
```

This method will sort "arrayOfObjects" by "name" property.
Method works fine, question is: 
how i can compare function call with different arguments

```
  it('should get correct comparison function', function () {
    const func = component.getComparisonFunction('testProperty');

    const expectedFunc = function(a, b){
      if ( a['testProperty'] < b['testProperty'] ) {
        return -1;
      }
      if ( a['testProperty'] > b['testProperty'] ) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    };

    expect(func.toString()).toEqual(expectedFunc.toString());
  });
```

This is what i have now, but it doesn't works. The error i am receiving after running the code is:

```
 Expected 'function (a, b) {
                if (a[propertyOfComparison] < b[propertyOfComparison]) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a[propertyOfComparison] > b[propertyOfComparison]) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }' to equal 'function (a, b) {
                if (a['testProperty'] < b['testProperty']) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a['testProperty'] > b['testProperty']) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }'.
```

Comment: Checking the stringified function is ***very*** brittle, as you just experienced. Typically, you test the *behaviour*, and don't expect an extra newline or a semi colon or anything inconsequential break your tests. So, make a list that you know how you want sorted, sort it, and then check if the sort order is the same as what you expect.

Comment: Thing is i don't want to test a comparison function, it works fine. I am testing right now if "getComparisonFunction()" is returning the value i am expecting, or not.

Comment: And I'm saying this is the wrong approach. You almost never want to test the exact implementation much less at the level of detail you try to. You test behaviour, in order to be able to *change the implementation*. If you change the implementation now, your test is instantly worthless - you can *change the test* but you cannot be sure that the newly returned function behaves the same way as the old one.

Comment: I got the point, thank you @VLAZ!
Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: this is where typescript and following strict typing can make this easier

Comment: @Ctfrancia I don't see how this is relevant when you want to test functionality. Strict typing only ensures that you pass numbers where you expect numbers and similar. It doesn't ensure that using the numbers is correct, e.g., `function add(a: number, b: number): number { return a * b; }` will be correct as far as TS is concerned but does not produce a correct result. Just because code compiles [doesn't mean it doesn't have bugs](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/Flawless-Compilation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the code of the function as a test ***very*** brittle and can break easily giving you a false negative:

```js
let someFn = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

let expected = `function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}`

console.log("Test original implementation:", test(someFn.toString(), expected));

//later the code style is changed to remove extra whitespace and make it one line
someFn = function(a, b) { return a+b; }

console.log("Test updated implementation:", test(someFn.toString(), expected));

//simple testing
function test(expected, actual) {
  return expected == actual
}
```

Just making non-functional changes to the code breaks the test.

Worse yet, if there *are* functional changes to the code, the test cannot guarantee that the new implementation behaves like the old one, since it only looks at the structure of the code:

```js
//simplified case of what the actual code could be doing
function someCodeBaseFunction() {
  let someInput = [8, 12, 42];
  return someFn(...someInput)
}

let someFn = function(a, b) { return a+b; }

let expected = `function(a, b) { return a+b; }`

console.log("Test original implementation:", test(someFn.toString(), expected));

console.log("Codebase usage:", someCodeBaseFunction()); //20, as the third number is ignored

//new implementation
someFn = function(...args) { 
  return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b); 
}

//update the test, so it passes
expected = `function(...args) { 
  return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b); 
}`

console.log("Test updated implementation:", test(someFn.toString(), expected));

//some existing line of code
console.log("Codebase usage:", someCodeBaseFunction()); //62, as the third number is now used

//simple testing
function test(expected, actual) {
  return expected == actual
};
```

Instead, what you want to do it test the *behaviour* of the code and set your expectations there. That way, if the implementation changes, you can make sure that the implementation still conforms to the same set of expectations.

In this case, you need to create a sample input that is initially unordered, try to order it and then expect that the order worked as you expected. In pseudo-code that would look a bit like this:

```
//arrange
input = [
 {testProperty: "c", id: 1},
 {testProperty: "a", id: 2},
 {testProperty: "d", id: 3},
 {testProperty: "b", id: 4}
];

expected = [
 {testProperty: "a", id: 2},
 {testProperty: "b", id: 4},
 {testProperty: "c", id: 1},
 {testProperty: "d", id: 3}
];

//act
input.sort(component.getComparisonFunction('testProperty'))

//assert
expect(input).toEqual(expected);
```

You can also add more tests at a more granular level to bind the expectations even more, if you want. For example, if you want to ensure that the comparison is case-sensitive

```
//arrange
a = { testProperty: "a" };
b = { testProperty: "B" };

//act
result = component.getComparisonFunction('testProperty')(a, b)

//assert
expect(result).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1)
```

Or case-insensitive:

```
//arrange
a = { testProperty: "a" };
b = { testProperty: "B" };

//act
result = component.getComparisonFunction('testProperty')(a, b)

//assert
expect(result).toBeLessThanOrEqual(-1)
```

This defines your expectations much more clearly and makes sure that future changes will cover exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve sort via any param provided, you can try following :

```
const array=[
  {name:'C',Key:'14',val:3},
  {name:'B',Key:'12',val:2},
  {name:'A',Key:'11',val:1},
  {name:'D',Key:'16',val:4},
  {name:'E',Key:'18',val:5}
];

console.log(array);

function comparer(prop){
  return function(a,b){
    return a[prop]-b[prop];
  }
};
array.sort(comparer('Key'));
console.log(array);
array.sort(comparer('val'));
console.log(array);
```

Moreover, to test it simply have test cases like above and check if its sorting as per your implementation.